# Separate string paragraph with sentence

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, split

I´m trying to separate a string with paragrapghs (i.e actually they´re threads from an email), and I need to split the string based on a sentence of the string not just a word.

What I´ve tried is:

```
def split_text_from_sentence(text, sentence):
    chopped_text = re.split(sentence, text)
    return chopped_text
```

What I got:

```
full_text = ¨Good morning Carlos. We leave you attached the excel for info. Regards. Luis Miguel. Company Name blablabla From: Oscar Herrero, Carlos Sent: tuesday 25 of octoberFor: Administration Matter: [INTERNAL] Good afternoon, I need to ask you for a requirement to add in Sharepoint. Un saludo, Carlos OSCAR HERRERO engineering Support T8 1st floor | carlos.oscar-herrero@blabla.com¨

signature_text = ¨From: Oscar Herrero, Carlos Sent: tuesday 25 of octoberFor: Administration Matter: [INTERNAL]¨
```

And I´m looking to get something like:

```
first_message = ¨Good morning Carlos. We leave you attached the excel for info. Regards. Luis Miguel. Company Name blablabla ¨

rest_of_message = ¨Good afternoon, I need to ask you for a requirement to add in Sharepoint. Un saludo, Carlos OSCAR HERRERO engineering Support T8 1st floor | carlos.oscar-herrero@blabla.com¨
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def split_text_from_sentence(text, sentence):
    chopped_text = text.split(sentence)
    return chopped_text

full_text = "Good morning Carlos. We leave you attached the excel for info. Regards. Luis Miguel. Company Name blablabla From: Oscar Herrero, Carlos Sent: tuesday 25 of octoberFor: Administration Matter: [INTERNAL] Good afternoon, I need to ask you for a requirement to add in Sharepoint. Un saludo, Carlos OSCAR HERRERO engineering Support T8 1st floor | carlos.oscar-herrero@blabla.com"
signature_text = "From: Oscar Herrero, Carlos Sent: tuesday 25 of octoberFor: Administration Matter: [INTERNAL]"
first_message,rest_of_the_message= split_text_from_sentence(full_text,signature_text)
print(first_message,rest_of_the_message)
```

why are you using "re" when this can be done with string methods.